# Help with understanding factor groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm still struggling to undertand factor groups and quotient groups so I've been trying to think up some examples and I was wondering if you guys could tell me if my thinking is correct?
Say you have this:
$\mathbb Z/(3)$   Would this then be the set {1+$\mathbb Z/(3)$, 2+$\mathbb, Z/(3)$ 
0+$\mathbb Z/(3)$}

What is the difference between $\mathbb Z/(3)$ and $\mathbb Z/$$3\mathbb Z$?

Also all the quotient/factor groups I've seen tend to be under addition can anyone think of a simple example under multiplication? What if I have the rationals? $\mathbb Q/(3)$ Does that equal

{3*$\mathbb Q/3$,3*$\mathbb 2Q/3$, 3*$\mathbb Q$}  for example?

I'm not entirely sure what my confusion is I think I just need to see multiple examples, unfortunately my book doesn't provide very many examples. Also can someone explain the link between Modulo and factor groups?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Z}/(3)=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, given by $0+3\mathbb{Z}$, $1+3\mathbb{Z}$ and $2+3\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

$(3)$ is a way to define $3\mathbb Z$ as the smallest ideal containing the number $3$. If you don't know what an *ideal* is just assume that $(3)$ means $3\mathbb Z$.

In turn $3\mathbb Z = \{ 3z \colon z \in \mathbb Z\} = \{\text{multiples of $3$}\}$. The set $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ is the quotient where you identify elements if their difference is in $3\mathbb Z$ i.e. if they differ by a multiple of $3$. There are three equivalence classes which are $3\mathbb Z$, $1+3\mathbb Z$, $2+3\mathbb Z$. Notice for example that $10+3\mathbb Z$ = $1 + 9 + 3\mathbb Z$ = $1+\mathbb Z$.

Hence
$$
\mathbb Z / 3\mathbb Z = \{ \mathbb Z, 1+\mathbb Z, 2+\mathbb Z\}.
$$

About $\mathbb Q/3\mathbb Q$ notice that $3\mathbb Q = \mathbb Q$ since every rational number is a rational multiple of $3$. Hence that quotient is trivial: it has a single element which is $\mathbb Q$ itself.

Comment: I see, itmakes moree sense. I just can't seem to square the modular definition of factor groups with the definition revolving around cosets. It makes much more sense to think of it as partitions via a modular arithmetic. Thanks so much for your response

Comment: First imagine a set together with an equivalence relation.  This partitions the set into equivalence classes.  So in the case of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ we partition the integers into (1) all integers with remainder $0$ when divided by $3$, (2) all integers with remainder $1$, and (3) all integers with remainder $2$.  A quotient group is simply the natural way of turning these three *equivalence classes* into a group. It turns out the way we add equivalence classes is we simply take one representative of each class, add them normally, and find which class their sum falls into. That's it.